# Jasperreports - Hide duplicate field in report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm creating reports using Java and JasperReports. What I've got is a query that outputs hotel details in order of Hotel Name.

My problem is that, a lot of the time the Hotel Name field doesn't change from row to row. I want to find out how to only print each different hotel name once to stop the report printing unnecessary hotel names.

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Would a group not do what you want? You put the hotel name into a group and it will only be printed once.

Answer (score 2):

use the following option in your report element. `reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false".`

Answer (score 1):

You can uncheck the `Print Repeated Value` checkbox on the properties of the Text Field that displays the hotel name.