# Java Jasper Reports, Hiding particular column in a row but displaying rest of the information in that particular row

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using **iReport 1.2.7 tool** to create jasper reports.
I want to display '**Schedule Date** ', '**Engineer Name**' and '**Project ID**' on my report after fetching the details from the database. But I want the **Scheduled date to be printed only once for one particular Engineer**. Similarly, if an Engineer was involved in multiple projects, its Name should only be printed once, **but there should be multiple entries under Project_Id** column. Below Diagram will make the scenario clear :
[image]

Here, at entry number #1 and #3, Date is only printed once corresponding to that particular engineer and then **Engineer Name is printed only once with multiple project IDs**. I tried creating a variable which will store the last engineer name or the date field so that we may check if the current name is similar to the last. But can't find a way to point to the last fetched row from database.

Any help or direction in the same is highly appreciated.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953733/jasperreports-hide-duplicate-field-in-report

Comment: @Turo I already tried that link but that didn't work that's why I had to post my own question. 'Unchecking' the print repeat values solves the problem for not displaying same engineer name twice, but the date is still getting printed multiple times. IF I uncheck for date-field, it simply stops printing the date BUT it should print it for a 'different' engineer name. You see my point ?

Comment: And what about Matthew Farwell's suggestion(Grouping)?

Comment: @Turo Yes I read about it, and I tried creating my own Group in iReport, but as soon as I drop the 'DATE' field in that group, only first date ( 18/04/2017  in this case ) is shown and rest of the below dates aren't printed. Could you help me with correct condition to define in that group ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{Scheduled_Date}.toString()+$F{EngineerName}]]></groupExpression>
```

In the TextFields uncheck "print repeated values" and select your group in "print when group changes".